# Problem with Autocomplete from Material ui in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to implement an autocomplete to show suggestions in an input field and save the selection in the state so I googled to look for an AutoComplete library and found one from MaterialUI but I can't seem to get it to work.
I get both an error and a warning and can't quite wrap my head around how to solve them.

[image]

here's my code

```
<div className="App">
    <h1>Please Tell Diagnostica more medical info about you.</h1>
    <Container className='Diagnosis'>
      <Autocomplete
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={this.state.uuidFeatures}
        getOptionLabel={(feature) => feature.text}
        value={this.state.inputValue}}
        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
      />
    </Container>
  </div >
```

Comment: what do you get when you log feature.text? 
maybe try the optional chaining? feature?.text
seems that on first init it is still undefined

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i ended up using react-select and worked perfectly!